# IOS UiBarButtoItemn is not removed when changing ViewController in UITabBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uitabbar

I have created programmatically 2 UIBarButtonItem from a UIButton. The Nav Controller is in a UITabBar. When I move to another controller in the same UITabBar, these 2 UIBarButton do not get removed. Anyone has an idea on how to delete these 2 UIBarButtonItem

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    // Left Tab Bar Items
    UIButton *fbutton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [fbutton setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"ble"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [fbutton addTarget:self action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    fbutton.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 48  , 48);
    UIBarButtonItem *fBLEItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:fbutton];
    fBLEItem.enabled = NO;

    UIButton *tbutton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [tbutton setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"ble"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [tbutton addTarget:self action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    tbutton.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 48, 48);
    UIBarButtonItem *tBLEItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tbutton];
    tBLEItem.enabled = NO;

    self.tabBarController.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = YES;
    self.tabBarController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = @[fBLEItem,tBLEItem];

}


- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:NO];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:nil animated:NO];

}
```

Comment: Don't forget `[super viewWillDisappear:animated];`
and `[super viewWillAppear:animated];`

Comment: To make your code more readable please add 4 spaces to the beginning of each line.  That will help us help you.

Comment: Why go not just do:
 `UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ble"]  style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(mySelector)];`

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `UIBarButtonItem` on `self.tabBarController.navigationItem` but then setting `nil` on `self.navigationItem`.  These are two different things.  Try:

```
[self.tabBarController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:NO]; 
[self.tabBarController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:nil animated:NO];
```